# Dynamically remove Mapbox 3D terrain in Mapbox-GL

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm using mapbox-3d-terrain with the new version of mapbox-gl. We want to give our users the option to switch back to 2D. I would like to be able to

1. unset Terrain
2. then remove the source

This is the function to switch it 'on'.

```
    // manage 3D terrain
    enable3DTerrain() {
        try {
            this.map.addSource('mapbox-dem-2', {
                "type": "raster-dem",
                "url": "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-dem-v1",
                "tileSize": 512,
            });
            this.map.setTerrain({ "source": "mapbox-dem-2", 'exaggeration': 1.5 });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log({ e });
        }
    },
```

Is there a map function for unsetting terrain? Currently I am  restarting / rebuilding / reloading the map completely to remove the 3D terrain, which is not how I want to implement my solution.

Answer (score 5):

I found a simple solution how to switch map back to 2D:

```
this.map.setTerrain();
```

It works without restarting or reloading.
Then you can remove the source, and add it again if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same use case. After playing around,

I found that changing `{'exaggeration': 0}` value to **0** in

`this.map.setTerrain({ "source": "mapbox-dem-2", 'exaggeration': 1.5 })`
displays the 2D view of the map.

If elevation of the map exists, set `maxPitch: 0` or `pitch: 0` in your **initialViewState** or **viewState** of the map conditionally to toggle between 2D & 3D.